# MATLAB - Creating a matrix of lagged time step vectors (similar to padding?)

Tags: matlab, padding, forecasting

I have a 429x1 vector that represents a hydrological time series.  I am looking to "lag" the time series by a time step and turn it into a matrix for input into the nftool for some ANN analysis.  The width of the matrix is controlled by the amount of input neurons in my input layer, which is a value I read in from a spread sheet.  This is what I would like to do using a shorter time series to illustrate the example:

```
    inp_neur = 5; % amount of input neurons (read in from excel)
A = [9;6;8;3;2]; % hypothetical hydrological time series

% do pad zero process
```

RESULT:

> newA =

```
 9     0     0     0     0
 6     9     0     0     0
 8     6     9     0     0
 3     8     6     9     0
 2     3     8     6     9
```

I'm sure this isn't the hardest thing to do, but can it be done in a one liner?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

JQ

```
Another example with inp_neur = 7;

A = [11;35;63;21;45;26;29;84;51]
```

newA =

```
11  0   0   0   0   0   0
35  11  0   0   0   0   0
63  35  11  0   0   0   0
21  63  35  11  0   0   0
45  21  63  35  11  0   0
26  45  21  63  35  11  0
29  26  45  21  63  35  11
84  29  26  45  21  63  35
51  84  29  26  45  21  63
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the rules for getting `newA` from `A`? In particular, why does the first and second off-diagonal appear as they do? Did you mean for the first off-diagonal to be `8 8 8 8` and the second to be `6 6 6`?

Comment: Are you **sure** your first example doesn't contain a typo? It is inconsistent with your second example. Currently the third column in your first example `newA` is `0 0 9 8 6`, which implies a re-ordering of observations. Specifically, can you double check that you didn't mean the third column to be `0 0 9 6 8`, and the fourth column to be `0 0 0 9 6`? Also, if you are writing a comment addressed to a particular user, please use the @ symbol in front of their username. It will alert us to your comment, eg to alert me, you would use @ColinTBowers in your comment

Comment: @ColinTBowers my sincere apologies, I corrected the mistake in my first example, it should be inline with the second example now.  You're correction is much appreciated.

Comment: No worries. I have provided an additional answer that I think you should check out. The method of 3lectrologos will work, but will be **very** inefficient if the number of observations is greater than `inp_neur`. A loop solution would be much faster. But if you have the econometrics toolbox (the student edition has this), it contains a single function that does exactly what you want - see my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that this question has already been marked accepted, however, I think it is worth pointing out that the current accepted answer will be **very** inefficient if `T` (the number of observations in the time series) is much larger than `K` (the number of lags, ie `inp_neur` in the OP's notation). This is because it creates a `T` by `T` matrix then truncates it to `T` by `K`.

I would propose two possible alternatives. The first uses a function from the Econometrics toolbox designed to do exactly what the OP wants: `lagmatrix`. The second is a loop based solution.

The `lagmatrix` solution returns `NaN` where the OP wants `0`, so an additional line is necessary to convert them. The full solution is:

```
newA2 = lagmatrix(A, 0:K-1);
newA2(isnan(newA2)) = 0;
```

The loop based solution is:

```
newA3 = zeros(T, K);
for k = 1:K
    newA3(k:end, k) = A(1:end-k+1);
end
```

The obvious advantage of the loop based solution is that it does not require the econometrics toolbox. But is that the only advantage? Let's try some timed runs. Set `T = K = 10`. Then:

```
Elapsed time is 0.045809 seconds. %# 3lectrologos solution
Elapsed time is 0.049845 seconds. %# lagmatrix solution
Elapsed time is 0.017340 seconds. %# loop solution
```

3lectrologos solution and the `lagmatrix` solution are essentially the same. The loop based solution is 3 times faster! Now, to emphasize the problem with 3lectrologos solution, set `T = 1000` and `K = 10`. Then:

```
Elapsed time is 10.615298 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.149164 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.056074 seconds.
```

Now 3lectrologos solution is two orders of magnitude slower than the `lagmatrix` solution. But the real winner on the day is the loop based solution that still manages to be 3 times faster than the `lagmatrix` solution.

**Conclusion:** Don't discount single-loops in Matlab anymore. They are getting really fast!

For those who are interested, the code for the timed runs is below:

```
M = 1000; %# Number of iterations for timed test
T = 1000; %# Length of your vector of inputs
K = 10; %# Equivalent to your inp_neur
A = randi(20, T, 1); %# Generate random data

%# 3lectrologos solution (inefficient if T is large relative to K)
tic
for m = 1:M
    tmp = tril(toeplitz(A));
    newA1 = tmp(:, 1:K);
end
toc

%# lagmatrix solution
tic
for m = 1:M
    newA2 = lagmatrix(A, 0:K-1);
    newA2(isnan(newA2)) = 0;
end
toc

%# Loop based solution
tic
for m = 1:M
    newA3 = zeros(T, K);
    for k = 1:K
        newA3(k:end, k) = A(1:end-k+1);
    end
end
toc
```

Comment: thank you for your alternate solutions, your methods are more appropriate for my needs as my time series is generally in the magnitude of 100X the size of my input neuron size.  Your solution is streamlined and correct.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a two liner:

```
tmp = tril(toeplitz(A));
newA = tmp(:, 1:inp_neur);
```

Comment: This doesn't reproduce the `newA` provided in the question (check the first and second off-diagonal) - although I wouldn't rule out the possibility that your solution is correct and the question contains a typo :-) I've asked the OP for greater clarification.

Comment: The OP is asking for "lagged" versions of `A`, so I assume it's a typo.

Comment: Sorry 3lectro that is not what I am trying to do.  Mr. Bowers, no what you mention about the off-diagonal is not what I am trying to do.  I am using this data for one step ahead forecasting purposes using ANNs.  My input time series is vector A, I am trying to grow vector A into a matrix controlled by the amount of input neurons in my input layer (inp_neur).  By "growing" 'A' I am lagging a time step behind for each new column of newA.  As you will see in each column of newA, the vector "slides" down a row as you progress through the columns.  Please let me know if this clears up your question

Comment: I also placed another example above my in original post.

Comment: @thatWaterGuy Well OK, it's not that different. Just keep the first `inp_neur` columns of the matrix in my original answer (see updated code above).

Comment: @3lectrologos This will work, but it will be very inefficient if `length(A)` is large relative to `inp_neur` - and the question suggests this is the case. I've provided two alternate solutions in my answer and performed some timed runs that may be of interest. Cheers.